# Display gridview in new window

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, session-variables

Just a bit of advice needed really in terms of how I should handle my current scenario:

I have a web page that searches for products/category information the results of which are at present displayed in a gridview on the same page.

However, said gridview is a bit of a beast and as such, I would like to have a page that the user searches for, a button is pressed and the subsequent gridview is displayed in a new window.

Ultimately, I would like the user to be able to make multiple searches so that new windows can have multiple gridviews containing different data sets.

My current thinking is to create session variables that can be pulled through onto 'the gridview page'. Having said that, I'm not sure that would work if multiple searches are created?

I am also thinking I might be able to create said 'gridview window' using javascript but my concern here is the potential loss of functionality of the gridview i.e. paging, sorting, editing, etc.

Does anyone have any thoughts or theories on this? What would be "best practise"? Any thoughts greatly appreciated and taken on board.

PS: This is being developed in .net, using c# and LINQ. 
PPS: I'm a noob so be gentle!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of sessions here right ? well on your first page where you enter search query, when user clicks on the button open the search result page in a  new window with a query string may be search.aspx?keyword=foo.

so everytime user clicks on search button it keeps on opening new windows. u can javascript to open the new popup window and set "target" attribute to "Blank" so it will open in new window